# Selecting rows by data corresponding to other rows of the same dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling in selecting the rows of my dataframe. The selection is depedening on the data inside the same dataframe.

My dataset looks something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
columns = ['Id', 'ActorId', 'EventId', 'Time']
vals = [(3,  3, 'START', '2020-06-22'), 
        (4,  3, 'END',   '2020-06-24'), 
        (5,  3, 'OTHER', '2019-01-15'), 
        (6,  3, 'OTHER', '2020-07-24'), 
        (7,  3, 'OTHER', '2020-06-23'), 
        (8,  4, 'START', '2018-01-15'), 
        (9,  4, 'END',   '2019-01-14'), 
        (10, 4, 'OTHER', '2018-11-14')]
events = sc.createDataFrame(vals,columns)
events.show()
```

Which results in:

```
+---+-------+-------+----------+
| Id|ActorId|EventId|      Time|
+---+-------+-------+----------+
|  3|      3|  START|2020-06-22|
|  4|      3|    END|2020-06-24|
|  5|      3|  OTHER|2019-01-15|
|  6|      3|  OTHER|2020-07-24|
|  7|      3|  OTHER|2020-06-23|
|  8|      4|  START|2018-01-15|
|  9|      4|    END|2019-01-14|
| 10|      4|  OTHER|2018-11-14|
+---+-------+-------+----------+
```

(Bear in mind, that this is just an example -> an extract of the data)

I want to find all rows with EventId==OTHER, where time is not between the START and END Events of the same ActorId.
The result should look like:

```
+---+-------+-------+----------+
| Id|ActorId|EventID|      Time|
+---+-------+-------+----------+
|  5|      3|  OTHER|2019-01-15|
|  6|      3|  OTHER|2020-07-24|
+---+-------+-------+----------+
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: will that start and end value will remain in the first and second position always ?

Comment: Important question! Unfortunately not, but I added a version of your code as a comment, that should ensure that the order does not matter

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem - There is only 1 assumption in the below code that START and END in the eventId colum will always appear in the 1st and 2nd line in each group.

```
_w = W.partitionBy('ActorId').orderBy('ActorId')


events = events.withColumn('start_date', F.first('Time').over(_w))
events = events.withColumn('row_num', F.row_number().over(_w))
events = events.withColumn('end_date', F.when(F.col('row_num') == F.lit('2'), F.col('Time')))
events = events.withColumn('end_date', F.coalesce(F.when(F.col('row_num') == F.lit('2'), F.col('Time')), F.min('end_date').over(_w)))
events = events.withColumn('passed_col', F.when(
  (
    ((F.col('Time').cast(T.TimestampType()) > F.col('start_date').cast(T.TimestampType())) & (F.col('Time').cast(T.TimestampType()) > F.col('end_date').cast(T.TimestampType()))) |
                                                                                            
    (
      (F.col('Time').cast(T.TimestampType()) < F.col('start_date').cast(T.TimestampType()))
                                                & (F.col('Time').cast(T.TimestampType()) < F.col('end_date').cast(T.TimestampType())))),F.lit("Passed")))

events = events.select('Id', 'ActorId', 'EventId', 'Time', 'passed_col')
events.show() 

+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
| Id|ActorId|EventId|      Time|passed_col|
+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
|  3|      3|  START|2020-06-22|      null|
|  4|      3|    END|2020-06-24|      null|
|  5|      3|  OTHER|2019-01-15|    Passed|
|  6|      3|  OTHER|2020-07-24|    Passed|
|  7|      3|  OTHER|2020-06-23|      null|
|  8|      4|  START|2018-01-15|      null|
|  9|      4|    END|2019-01-14|      null|
| 10|      4|  OTHER|2018-11-14|      null|
+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Final Answer post filtering ---

```
events = events.filter(F.col('passed_col') == F.lit('Passed')).select('Id', 'ActorId', 'EventId', 'Time', 'passed_col')
events.show()

+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
| Id|ActorId|EventId|      Time|passed_col|
+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
|  5|      3|  OTHER|2019-01-15|    Passed|
|  6|      3|  OTHER|2020-07-24|    Passed|
+---+-------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That helped a lot!
I ended up selecting the START and END Date by:
events = events.withColumn('start_date', F.when(F.col('EventId') == F.lit('START'), F.col('Time')))
events = events.withColumn('end_date', F.when(F.col('EventId') == F.lit('END'), F.col('Time')))

That way the order shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: withColumn() will iterate through each row, so in your datafram START and END present 4 times, so both the new column which has been credited will produce null value where there's not a matching. Example row : 3, 4, 5 6

Comment: Thats correct! I just use it to replace your first three lines. Then I used the coalesce function just like you, except that I didn't created a row_number but instead used the EventId like so:
events = events.withColumn('start_date', F.coalesce(F.when(F.col('EventId') == F.lit('START'), F.col('Time')), F.min('start_date').over(_w)))
events = events.withColumn('end_date', F.coalesce(F.when(F.col('EventId') == F.lit('END'), F.col('Time')), F.max('end_date').over(_w)))

Answer (score 0):

```
 val res = vals
  .filter('EventId.equalTo("OTHER"))
  .filter('ActorId.equalTo(3))
  .filter(!'Time.between("2020-06-01","2020-06-25"))

  res.show(false)
//  +---+-------+-------+----------+
//  |Id |ActorId|EventId|Time      |
//  +---+-------+-------+----------+
//  |5  |3      |OTHER  |2019-01-15|
//  |6  |3      |OTHER  |2020-07-24|
//  +---+-------+-------+----------+
```

or

```
      val res = vals
    .filter('EventId.equalTo("OTHER"))
    .filter(!'Time.between("2018-01-01","2018-12-31"))
    .filter(!'Time.between("2020-06-01","2020-06-25"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't mention that my table contains a lot of more data, with a lot of more actors and events, where the specific times wouldn't match. I'm looking for a little more generalized ways